# VSCode mainstram support

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the mainstream support end date for the current version of VSCode, or usually how much days a each new release of the vscode app will get supported from Microsoft? If possible please include any reference link for the same.

I need to share this info with the OS Packaging team within my organization to package vscode with Win 10 OS. I haven't found any official documentation on this. Someone please help to get me this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode software doesn't provide any technical support constrains, neither updates or bugfixes SLAs. You can try to contact Microsoft representatives if you need a commercial license which includes better warranties.

from the [licence](https://code.visualstudio.com/license):

**DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTY. The software is licensed “as-is.” You bear the risk of using it. Microsoft gives no express warranties, guarantees or conditions. To the extent permitted under your local laws, Microsoft excludes the implied warranties of merchantability, fitness for a particular purpose and non-infringement.**